# WCF and REST app using different endpoints on the same port, is this ok?

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, windows-services, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a WCF app (app A) that's been running for years on port XXX3, now I have created a RESTful version of the same app (app B).  I initially wanted to set up app B on port XXX4 but I have to deal with corporate security policies that block ports.

If I run app B on port XXX3, it appears to run fine, and app A doesn't appear to have any issues either.

I have always been under the impression that a given app should use its own port... so I was concerned there would be conflicts between app A and B if on the same port.  Should I be concerned about conflicts or is this a non-issue?  Everything I read seems to indicate as well that they should be on different ports.

One final piece of info... due to app A being WCF and app B being a .NET Core web api app, they both use different endpoints, so I suspect that is why there don't appear to be any conflicts.  Is it the endpoints themselves that determine where the port data gets routed?  Can anyone give a simple networking explanation as to why this appears to be working with them both on the same port and if it's ok to leave it running this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> WCF and REST app using different endpoints on the same port, is this ok?

TL;DR: yes.

> I have always been under the impression that a given app should use its own port

Generally yes.

> Should I be concerned about conflicts or is this a non-issue?
> No. WCF apps hosted in IIS have had the ability to share ports for sometime now. (below)

WCF apps have had the ability to share ports for [sometime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/net-tcp-port-sharing) now when hosted over IIS.

This is what MSDN [has to say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/net-tcp-port-sharing) (my emphasis):

> The ability to share ports across multiple HTTP applications has long been a feature of Internet Information Services (IIS). However, it was only with the introduction of **HTTP.SYS** (the kernel-mode HTTP protocol listener) with IIS 6.0 that this infrastructure was fully generalized. In effect, HTTP.SYS **allows arbitrary user processes to share the TCP ports** dedicated to HTTP traffic. This capability allows many HTTP applications to coexist on the **same physical machine** in separate, isolated processes while sharing the network infrastructure required to send and receive traffic over TCP port 80. The Net.TCP Port Sharing Service enables the same type of port sharing for **net.tcp** applications.

Meanwhile, .NET Core apps can also benefit from TCP port sharing via HTTP.sys, a web server implemenation in ASP.NET Core.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

> HTTP.sys is a web server for ASP.NET Core that only runs on Windows.
>
> HTTP.sys supports the following features:
>
> - Windows Authentication
> - **Port sharing** ...

OP

> One final piece of info... due to app A being WCF and app B being a .NET Core web api app, they both use different endpoints, so I suspect that is why there don't appear to be any conflicts

They might have two different logical endpoints but both can share TCP 80 via the common HTTP.SYS.  It's no different to multiple WCF apps hosted in IIS all sharing `http://xxx:80/<service-suffix>`.

Comment: I guess I should have clarified these are self-hosted, not being run under IIS, BUT that doesn't change the fact that they are using HTTP.SYS.  Looks like you hit the nail on the head... I knew it was working but didn't realize why, now I know it was due to the HTTP.SYS web server implementation!

Comment: @eerick That's ok.  Yes, .NET Core generally wants to do its own thing and be cross platform so it doesn't want to depend on IIS.  It's great 'Core uses the shared HTTP.SYS so everyone gets along. :)  Thanks for accept